# Tortoisegit add operation

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have initialized a git repository (not a bare one) on my system. I observed that whenever I create a file and add it through Tortoisegit->add , the hash object created in the .git/objects folder is always in read-only mode.

Is this the functionality of Tortoisegit?  If yes, can this behavior be altered?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is discussed on https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/3056 and might be a bug in libgit2 a library which TortoiseGit uses.

Object files created by git.exe are also read-only on Windows, maybe libgit2 does the renaming different compared to git.exe.

A short workaround would be to disable the usage of libgit2 for Adding files to index, by setting the registry dword value "Software\TortoiseGit\UseLibgit2_mask" to 0x000031c0.